# How to custom Principle object with Spring Cloud Security?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I finally got my oauth2 server running.

From command line, if I run

```
curl -s -u acme:acmesecret -d grant_type=password -d username=myusername -d password=mypassword -H Accept:application/json http://localhost:9999/oauth/token
```

I got result below,

```
{
    "access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0Mzk1NDU3ODAsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6IisxIDQwODUxODIxMTUiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJVU0VSIiwiQURNSU4iXSwianRpIjoiYmFkMDgyMjctNDExNC00OTZkLWE1NDMtYzBhMjc3YTBhZDkzIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiYWNtZSIsInNjb3BlIjpbIndlYnNob3AiXX0.CM_0gBHVyecOMmpc2cnKTus48PNv8gfHDyzVOVa5TBDxv4QlnDO93otmUs86IQqPaqaI133tT1NPU0pt2dbV5lrY3FOlPFXB0zZw5ptIXCtpaQLgl3e9hkB1aSfv3YxbHiOV8n3FcvNdz9Ihi9XEQdzqT8YfK7mCeMOjdb1i6Ve9axwjJI9ZHxXzDMcJsnYBcQCKG52G3-rWzgzlaQkPZY6mO7q0eO0jgVWthLfSBumHlDt9QXaBkETH3CRHxSuJqlo4J3TZxP4-1vPLkgh8Ku2rY5A9rT-xOKG8_5s2CJduCZt0qQrXZhz7sk0m2IdxDDwXumPv6zyHyD2J3sjHUA",
"token_type": "bearer",
"refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiIrMSA0MDg1MTgyMTE1Iiwic2NvcGUiOlsid2Vic2hvcCJdLCJhdGkiOiJiYWQwODIyNy00MTE0LTQ5NmQtYTU0My1jMGEyNzdhMGFkOTMiLCJleHAiOjE0NDIwOTQ1ODAsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlVTRVIiLCJBRE1JTiJdLCJqdGkiOiJjYWNkOWEzOC1mOWE5LTQ4NjAtOWZmMi05NWMzMzU4MmY0NDAiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJhY21lIn0.DhaqIEdYWR2VPkgh72bQ17ZLqcVVfdYtT8DdKibjIcZUTNNjN_atdyKYKNEtdSyEES-ArHL0jCVXUg3EKiut_qtvn8oaLYEAxCNfztHyo_b-RZIxOgr71m82n66vSwRzxQnoKcGltxpZs-PK5p-gmbaEWK4EO63AkJpgN_IrIGV4eVQmidanz53rvq-CBiq-1FFb64OilesUxkSPOVkbb-q-mUmd8EG4khdbf44LD9VhyZwt8lOOi8NnksnnGhogiynU9p7tirAv6w_g8IO7uy06fWaLyn6rAgPga3CYgo9ggFIICWKn-QFipkHgiehq6y_1-xTGlgHnRKXcnPIZcg",
    "expires_in": 34996,
    "scope": "webshop",
    "jti": "bad08227-4114-496d-a543-c0a277a0ad93"
}
```

With the token returned, I can get user information with a curl command. You can a lot of user information in the response.

```
curl http://localhost:9999/user -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0Mzk1NDU3ODAsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6IisxIDQwODUxODIxMTUiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJVU0VSIiwiQURNSU4iXSwianRpIjoiYmFkMDgyMjctNDExNC00OTZkLWE1NDMtYzBhMjc3YTBhZDkzIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiYWNtZSIsInNjb3BlIjpbIndlYnNob3AiXX0.CM_0gBHVyecOMmpc2cnKTus48PNv8gfHDyzVOVa5TBDxv4QlnDO93otmUs86IQqPaqaI133tT1NPU0pt2dbV5lrY3FOlPFXB0zZw5ptIXCtpaQLgl3e9hkB1aSfv3YxbHiOV8n3FcvNdz9Ihi9XEQdzqT8YfK7mCeMOjdb1i6Ve9axwjJI9ZHxXzDMcJsnYBcQCKG52G3-rWzgzlaQkPZY6mO7q0eO0jgVWthLfSBumHlDt9QXaBkETH3CRHxSuJqlo4J3TZxP4-1vPLkgh8Ku2rY5A9rT-xOKG8_5s2CJduCZt0qQrXZhz7sk0m2IdxDDwXumPv6zyHyD2J3sjHUA" 

{
  "details": {
    "remoteAddress": "127.0.0.1",
    "sessionId": null,
    "tokenValue": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0Mzk1NDU3ODAsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6IisxIDQwODUxODIxMTUiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJVU0VSIiwiQURNSU4iXSwianRpIjoiYmFkMDgyMjctNDExNC00OTZkLWE1NDMtYzBhMjc3YTBhZDkzIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiYWNtZSIsInNjb3BlIjpbIndlYnNob3AiXX0.CM_0gBHVyecOMmpc2cnKTus48PNv8gfHDyzVOVa5TBDxv4QlnDO93otmUs86IQqPaqaI133tT1NPU0pt2dbV5lrY3FOlPFXB0zZw5ptIXCtpaQLgl3e9hkB1aSfv3YxbHiOV8n3FcvNdz9Ihi9XEQdzqT8YfK7mCeMOjdb1i6Ve9axwjJI9ZHxXzDMcJsnYBcQCKG52G3-rWzgzlaQkPZY6mO7q0eO0jgVWthLfSBumHlDt9QXaBkETH3CRHxSuJqlo4J3TZxP4-1vPLkgh8Ku2rY5A9rT-xOKG8_5s2CJduCZt0qQrXZhz7sk0m2IdxDDwXumPv6zyHyD2J3sjHUA",
    "tokenType": "Bearer",
    "decodedDetails": null
  },
  "authorities": [
    {
      "authority": "USER"
    },
    {
      "authority": "ADMIN"
    }
  ],
  "authenticated": true,
  "userAuthentication": {
    "details": {
      "grant_type": "password",
      "username": "myusername"
    },
    "authorities": [
      {
        "authority": "USER"
      },
      {
        "authority": "ADMIN"
      }
    ],
    "authenticated": true,
    "principal": {
      "id": "usr000d11b4c86-13ba-11e5-b905-56847afe9799",
      "json": null,
      "version": 0,
      "created": 1434412879774,
      "updated": 1438877901186,
      "info": {
        "nickName": "Kevin",
        "country": "China",
        "zipcode": null,
        "state": null,
        "city": "",
        "occupation": "",
        "gender": null,
        "imgPath": "https://ddbs0erhouflt.cloudfront.net/mcf000ecd36bcb-f33e-4d50-9102-7a8706b45eb8",
        "about": "",
        "dueDate": 1447312895201,
        "birthday": 0
      },
      "privateInfo": {
        "email": "zyj@yahoo.com",
        "phone": "myusername",
        "password": "f45206ce4247b5d9af350d4600adc85c",
        "tempPassword": null,
        "tokens": null
      },
      "settings": null,
      "type": "Super",
      "status": "Active",
      "enabled": true,
      "username": "myusername",
      "password": "f45206ce4247b5d9af350d4600adc85c",
      "accountNonExpired": true,
      "accountNonLocked": true,
      "credentialsNonExpired": true,
      "authorities": [
        {
          "authority": "USER"
        },
        {
          "authority": "ADMIN"
        }
      ]
    },
    "credentials": null,
    "name": "myusername"
  },
  "credentials": "",
  "oauth2Request": {
    "clientId": "acme",
    "scope": [
      "webshop"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "grant_type": "password",
      "username": "myusername"
    },
    "resourceIds": [],
    "authorities": [],
    "approved": true,
    "refresh": false,
    "redirectUri": null,
    "responseTypes": [],
    "extensions": {},
    "grantType": "password",
    "refreshTokenRequest": null
  },
  "principal": {
    "id": "usr000d11b4c86-13ba-11e5-b905-56847afe9799",
    "json": null,
    "version": 0,
    "created": 1434412879774,
    "updated": 1438877901186,
    "info": {
      "nickName": "Kevin",
      "country": "China",
      "zipcode": null,
      "state": null,
      "city": "",
      "occupation": "",
      "gender": null,
      "imgPath": "https://ddbs0erhouflt.cloudfront.net/mcf000ecd36bcb-f33e-4d50-9102-7a8706b45eb8",
      "about": "",
      "dueDate": 1447312895201,
      "birthday": 0
    },
    "privateInfo": {
      "email": "zyj@yahoo.com",
      "phone": "myusername",
      "password": "f45206ce4247b5d9af350d4600adc85c",
      "tempPassword": null,
      "tokens": null
    },
    "settings": null,
    "type": "Super",
    "status": "Active",
    "enabled": true,
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "f45206ce4247b5d9af350d4600adc85c",
    "accountNonExpired": true,
    "accountNonLocked": true,
    "credentialsNonExpired": true,
    "authorities": [
      {
        "authority": "USER"
      },
      {
        "authority": "ADMIN"
      }
    ]
  },
  "clientOnly": false,
  "name": "myusername"
}
```

I have a Spring boot micro service client. It uses spring-cloud-security. One of the web service was below,

```
@RequestMapping(value="getsth", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public SomeObject getsth(Principal principal) {
    ....
}
```

When method getsth is called, I can see an object of OAuth2Authentication was passed in. However, user information like user id, user phone number are missing.

My question: how can I get all the user information? Is there any way to custom the principal object?

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks freakman for answering my question. But the answer is not what I'm looking for. I actually already implemented customized UserDetails on my oauth server A side. It's something like "public class User extends implements UserDetails". Everything is working. 
My problem is that I have another oauth protected app B. It's an independent spring boot app annotated with @EnableOAuth2Resource. The code piece "public SomeObject getsth(Principal principal)" I mentioned above is on the server B side. My question is how to get a User object instead of a principal on app B.

Comment: I have the same situation. The Principal just contain the name of the authenticated user. I would like to get the users id/uuid/email as well that is part of my own UserDetailsService. @YongJiang Zhang, did you get this  working as you intended?

Comment: I have the same situation as yours too Filip, did you find any way to get the user id? It is so weird that it is not supported by default because userId is commonly used

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue.  I got it to work however.

I'm using JWT so might be slightly different to what you're doing, but the concept is the same.

First of all, I created a custom TokenServices to get the extra information out of the user and added it to the authentication object:

```
public class TafTokenServices extends DefaultTokenServices {

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken createAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    final TafUserDetails tafUserDetails = (TafUserDetails)authentication.getPrincipal();
    final Map<String, Object> tafInfo = new HashMap<>();
    tafInfo.put("EMAIL", tafUserDetails.getEmailAddress());
    authentication.setDetails(tafInfo);
    return super.createAccessToken(authentication);
}
```

}

Then configure your auth server to use it:

```
 @Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
                                                              .tokenServices(tafTokenServices());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerTokenServices tafTokenServices() {
        final TafTokenServices tafTokenServices = new TafTokenServices();
        final JwtTokenStore jwtTokenStore = new JwtTokenStore(this.jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        tafTokenServices.setTokenStore(jwtTokenStore);
        tafTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(this.jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        return tafTokenServices;
    }
```

Also in the auth server you need to then transfer the data out of the authentication object into the token with your own AccessTokenCoverter object:

```
public class TafJwtAccessTokenConverter extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {

private static final String EMAIL_KEY = "EMAIL";

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    final Map<String, Object> authDetails = (Map<String, Object>)authentication.getDetails();
    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken)accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(authDetails);
    return super.enhance(accessToken, authentication);
}

@Override
public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
    final OAuth2Authentication authentication =    super.extractAuthentication(map);
    final Map<String, String> details = new HashMap<>();
    details.put(EMAIL_KEY, (String)map.get(EMAIL_KEY));
    authentication.setDetails(details);
    return authentication;
    }
}
```

NOTE:  the enhance() method is called during creation of the token, so you need this in the auth server.

NOTE: extractAuthentication() is called in the downstream services during authentication, so this implementation needs to exist there as well.  You need to configure your resource server to use this AccessTokenConverter.

That will get the info into the token to pass downstream.  Note I didn't want to keep the data in the custom user object because I don't want to have my other services depend on that object.

The next step is to get the stuff out of the token and use it in your resource server. You do this by overriding extractAuthentication() to get the details from the map and put them into the authentication object.  They will now be available in your application by doing something like this:

```
private String getEmail() {
    final OAuth2Authentication auth = this.getAuthentication();
    final OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)auth.getDetails();
    final Map<String, Object> map = (Map)details.getDecodedDetails();
    return "Your email address is " + map.get("EMAIL");
}

private OAuth2Authentication getAuthentication() {
    return (OAuth2Authentication)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
}
```

I'm not sure this is right way to go, it's a bit fiddly.  I have an issue open here where there is a discussion about it:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/issues/85#issuecomment-165498497

Answer (score -1):

to customize it you have to provide your own UserDetailsService class:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
}
}
```

where `User` is your entity with all fields you require:

```
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {...
```

then you have to configure spring security to actually use your custom user details service. Something similar to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public  class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
}
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for.